# How to derive a PDF from a PMF using infinitesimals?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

How can we, in a constructive way, justify the concept of a continuous random variable and its PDF starting from the PMF of a discrete variable and then proceeding in the limit using infinitesimals? (Don't want it in epsilon delta calculus, but actually using infinitesimals).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the other way around: you define the cumulative distribution of the discrete variable through CDF of a continuous variable. Take a look at the construct [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function#Measure_theoretic_formulation), where the discrete variable's PMF is treated as a special case of PDF.

Comment: Continuity is an abstraction, the real line, calculus etc came only later. It's not the other way around, I want to see a derivation that justifies continous variables and pdfs from first principles.

Comment: @statslearner, good luck with your inquest, but that's not how it works in statistics. you don't generalize PMF into PDF. there's a little problem with discrete random variables - they're countable. continuous variables are not countable, so it take quite a bit of mental power to go from discrete to continuous.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense, probability is basically applied measure theory/analysis/calculus. Since I can formalize calculus from first principles with infinitesimals, I should be able to do the same with statistics/probability.

Comment: @statslearner, i'm not trying to dissuade you, I'm just noting that it's easy to extend from continuous to discrete, not the other way around. try generalizing the natural numbers into real one. it's not easy or natural (pun intended)

Comment: It seems to me there isn't any case where one would generalize from continuous to discrete. Discrete distributions come for free and naturally just from talking about probability of events and mapping countable sets of events into numbers. Continuous variables and densities that need a deeper justification, just like calculus, since we have an unocountable set of events and single events have probability zero and so on.

Comment: @statslearner, you're overlooking the point I'm trying to make here: it's not trivial to construct a real line from discrete points. It's easy to toss around the words like *infinitesimal*, but try now to glue them together into the real line. You'll quickly realize that it's very trick.

Comment: I agree, but that has already been done.I just want to see how to derive/interpret continuous variables and densities in the infinitesimal/non-standard analysis formalism.